# Issue with using a .net class in ironpython

Tags: ironpython

If I have a .Net class that is not part of any namespace then I'm not able to use it in ironpython.

Here is an example

Suppose I have a assembly FooLib.dll with the following class definition

//note the following class is not part of global namespace

> public class Foo { }

Now I try to use it in ironpython

> clr.AddReference("FooLib") # This call
>   succeeds.
>
> f = Foo()

The line **f= Foo()** returns the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined

I tried the following

> from FooLib import *
>
> f = Foo()

The line **from FooLib import ***  reports an error which does make sense as the from clause should be used on namespaces and not assemblies

However, If the class Foo belong to some namespace, then i don't have a problem importing in ironpython

So, my query is how do I use a .net class belonging to a global namespace from ironpython

regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a bare `import` like so:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("FooLib") # This call succeeds.
import Foo
f = Foo()
```