# How do I reference classes using IronPython?

Tags: .net, ironpython

I want to use IronPython as a simple test harness for a .net application.
I have created a project in Visual Studio 2008 and have an empty python source file.
I have added my assemblies to the project in Visual Studio.
I am familiar with general python programming.

How do I import and use classes from my referenced assemblies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should just be

```
import [namespace]
```

for common .NET libraries and namespaces, such as `System`

to use additional assemblies, first need to import `clr` then add a reference to additional assemblies

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Xml")
from System.Xml import *
```

Take a look at

- [CLR Inside Out - IronPython](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300810.aspx)
- [Introducing IronPython](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39904/1763/page/3)

Also, have a look at where you installed IronPython. There is a lot of detail in the Tutorial.htm that can be found in `\IronPython 2.0.1\Tutorial\Tutorial.htm`

You generally create instance of classes like so

```
from System.Collections import *
# create an instance of Hashtable
h = Hashtable() 

from System.Collections.Generic import *
# create an instance of List<string>
l = List[str]()
```

Comment: What about adding custom assemblies? I am having some trouble getting those to load.

Comment: Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/haibo_luo/archive/2007/09/25/5130072.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200182/how-to-use-a-c-dll-in-ironpython and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579922/issue-with-using-a-net-class-in-ironpython