# IronPython and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ironpython, poco

Possibly really simple question, but I'm new to IronPython.  I would like use IronPython to crawl an entity I pass to it, but when I try to use any extension methods, it, as sort of expected, blows up.  How do I traverse my POCOs in IronPython?

```
delegate bool EvaluateRule(MyEntity entity);
//Keep in mind this is just to test, no actual value provided
string expression = @"entity.Flags.FirstOrDefault() == null";
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
PythonEngine engine = new PythonEngine();
EvaluateRule rule = engine.CreateLambda<EvaluateRule>(expression);
bool result = rule.Invoke(entity);
```

I get the following: 'EntityCollection[MyEntity]' object has no attribute 'FirstOrDefault'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "it, as sort of expected, blows up"?  What does this mean?  1) provide the smallest piece of code that shows the error.  2) provide the error.  Our ESP isn't all that good.  We can't guess what you've done or what "blows up" means.

Comment: Sorry, @S.Lott, was trying to be ambiguous as I was hoping for ideas without my implementation in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the extension methods as regular static methods:

```
string expression = @"Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(entity.Flags) == null";
```

Comment: If I do that, I get "name 'Enumerable' not defined"

Comment: [It's in System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx). You may need to reference that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to IronPython, how do I reference a namespace in my example above for IP to use?

Comment: With [import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579922/issue-with-using-a-net-class-in-ironpython/1579940#1579940)